# Async function is not working for me it's is showing error

Tags: html, angular, typescript

**I have an issue while displaying categories.I am trying this by using

> async

function but it is not showing  data**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select id="category" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">{{
        c.name
      }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

**I already tried this but it is not working**

**product-form.component.ts**

```
export class ProductFormComponent {
  categories$;

  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }
}
```

**And here i am create product data**

```
save(product) {
    this.productService.create(product);
    console.log(product);
  }
```

**category.service.ts**
**By using

> .valueChanges

I am able to get data but it is not storing data in firebase db. It is showing undefined**

```
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getCategories() {
    return this.db.list('/categories').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

**For creating product data and pushing it db i used this method**
**product.service.ts**

```
export class ProductService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  create(product) {
    return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
  }
}
```

**This is error i am getting**

> InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**List Categories:**

Modify `getCategories()`. Add `snapshotChanges()` or `valueChanges()`

Try like this:

```
return this.db.list('/categories').snapshotChanges();
```

or,

```
return this.db.list('/categories').valueChanges();
```

**Create Product:**

`$products: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;`

```
create(product) {
     return this.$products.push(product);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adrita . it is working but by using .valueChanges() is displaying data but to store data in db even after we select categories in form. It is showing undefined

Comment: You haven't shared for adding category in db, I added code for adding products. `this.$products.push(product)`